# How to add value of column in Parse?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, addition

```
ParseObject money = new ParseObject("Money");
money.put("value", value);
money.put("description", description);

money.saveInBackground();
```

I'm working on an application for Android, it's kind of calculator. I add data to parse how much money I earn and how much money I spend, so every row have value (how much money) and description. Now I need to add up all values from the column "value" and show it in another Activity.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to calculate the total value:

```
private int getTotal() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Money");
    try {
        int total = 0;
        List<ParseObject> objects = query.find();
        for (ParseObject p : objects) {
            total += p.getInt("value");
        }
        return total;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: And how to set this value to TextView?
(Sorry, I'm beginner)

Comment: You can pass the value as a string to [TextView.setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence).

Comment: `saldo.setText(String.valueOf(total));
 return total;`
I've this one, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Parse doesn't support aggregations via a query. You'll need to use CloudCode to do that, check out this example: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions